# How to display popover only to few columns if the table is reusable?

Tags: html, angular, tooltip, popover

I am using a popover inside a data table where it will show for every table data / columns. I am reusing the same data table in few other places as well. But however i don't need to display popover for every columns there, instead i want to restrict it only to few columns. how can i do that?

HTML:

```
<span
    [ngbPopover]="datapopover"
    container="body"
    class="cursor-pointer"
    popoverClass="hover-class"
    triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
    (mouseover)="showpopover(element,i,p1,column)"
    #p1="ngbPopover">
</span>
```

Method:

```js
showpopover(row) {
    this.rowSelected = row;
}
```

Reuse data:

```
<app-data-table
    [tableData]="partsData"
    [showhover]=true
    (editEvent)="edit($event)"
    (deleteEvent)="delete($event)"
></app-data-table>
```

Comment: please provide ur code

Comment: Dude :D please edit your original post instead of pasting it to the comments.

Comment: We need your hole `app-data-table` html so we can check how your colums look like. After this we can decide how to modify your component. First thought is to add another input like tableData called `popOverColumns` which is an string array. Inside your DataTableComponent you add a check on each column which looks up their key inside this string array. If the string array contains the key it adds the popover for the column, if not not.

Comment: you can add a condition in your mouseover, e.g. `(mouseover)="(column=='id' || column=='name') && showpopover(element,i,p1,column)"`, but it's difficult say more much about the problem with so few data

Comment: @liqSTAR let me try your suggestion first, i think that can solve my problem, i will get back to u after that , thanks.